# How to display info for all students with conflicting fields in Java

Tags: java, oop, static

I am still a noob in object-oriented programming so I want to ask how to run this line in Main.java: `Student.displayInfo(students);` If I try to place a static modifier in the methods and variables, the conditional statements will react violently. Can you tell me how to do it?

Main.java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {
    public void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        Student[] students = new Student[3];
        for (Student student : students) {
            System.out.println("Can you code: (y/n) ");
            student.canCode = (in.next().charAt(0) == 'y' || in.next().charAt(0) == 'Y');
        }
        Student.displayInfo(students);
    }
}
```

Student.java

```
public class Student {
    boolean canCode = false;

    public boolean getCodingSkill() {
        return canCode;
    }
    public void displayInfo(Student [] students) {      
        for (Student student : students) {
            if (getCodingSkill())
                System.out.println("I can code.");
            else System.out.println("I can't code.");

            System.out.println("\n===================="); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please read [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly. "react violently" does not tell us anything what is going on.

Comment: When You add `static` for method `displayInfo`, what's happen?

Comment: @newOne Errors on the conditional statements say that non-static variable canCode cannot be initialized from static context.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your question correctly, then this would be my answer:

StudentDetails.java:

```
package TrialPrograms;


public class StudentDetails {
    private static String firstname = "";
    private static String lastname = "";
    private static boolean cancode = false;
    private static boolean iscoding = false;

    public void setFname(String name) {
    this.firstname=name;
    }

    public String getFname() {
        return this.firstname;
    }

    public void setLname(String name) {
        this.lastname=name;
        }

        public String getLname() {
            return this.lastname;
        }

    public void setCanCode(boolean cancode) {
        this.cancode=cancode;

    }
    public boolean getCanCode() {
        return this.cancode;

    }
    public void setIsCoding(boolean iscoding) {
        this.iscoding=iscoding;

    }
    public boolean getIsCoding() {
        return this.iscoding;

    }

    public void displayInfo(){              
        System.out.println("Student Records");
        System.out.println("=========================================================");        
        //for (Student student : students) {
            System.out.println("Name: " + firstname+ " " + lastname);
            if (cancode==true) {
                if (iscoding==true) {
                    System.out.println(firstname + " is coding!!!");
                }
                else System.out.println(firstname + " can code.");
            }

             System.out.println("\n========================================================="); 
        }
    }
```

Main.java:

```
package TrialPrograms;


import java.util.Scanner;


class Main extends StudentDetails{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        StudentDetails stud = new StudentDetails();
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int noofstudents=3;

        for (int i=1;i<=noofstudents;i++) {
            System.out.println("Please enter your first name: ");
            stud.setFname(in.next());
            System.out.println("Please enter your last name: ");
            stud.setLname(in.next());
            System.out.println("Can you code: (y/n) ");
            if (in.next().charAt(0) == 'y' || in.next().charAt(0) == 'Y') {
                stud.setCanCode(true);
                System.out.println("Are you coding right now: (y/n) ");
                if(in.next().charAt(0) == 'y' || in.next().charAt(0) == 'Y') {
                    stud.setIsCoding(true);
                }else {
                    stud.setIsCoding(false);
                }
            }else {
                stud.setCanCode(false);
            }
            System.out.println("Loop is over");
            stud.displayInfo();
        }
        in.close();

    }
}
```

Hope this code answers your question.